# Database and table structure for larger logging application in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am thinking of building a logging application. I was planning on making it in Ruby on Rails since I have fiddled around with it a little and it seems lika a good option.

But what I now am worried about is the database structure. As I can understand Rails will create a table for every Model.

So if I have a model like: LoggingInstance, that stores the time of the logging, sensorID, value, unit and some other interesting stuff every 10th second. After a while I will have very many rows in this table. And as I add on more sensors the rows will increase even faster.

I could make the logging entires more specific like: TemperatureLoggingInstance, PressureLoggingInstance etc, but this might lead to the same performance problems.

What I am wondering is for a better way to store all the data. I was thinking if it was possible to save every sensors logging values in separate tables but how would I implement that in Rails. Or is there a better way of doing it?

I am afraid of getting bad performance in the database when I call the values from one sensor.

I was planning to use the RailsAPI gem and have one application running only data handling and then a front end application that would use the API to visualize the data.

The performance problem might not become a problem in years but I would want to structure the database so that it is possible to have a lot of data in it and have good performance.

All tips or references are appriciated :)

Comment: I guess you don't need a relational database for your task. You don't have to use `ActiveRecord` with rails, you can use every database you like actually

Comment: A traditional RDBMS like MySQL isn't a great fit for logging, for the reasons you've mentioned. The correct solution will depend entirely on your use case, though. How many writes will you have per hour? Per month? How do you want to access the data (simple filtering, complex queries?), and how often?

Comment: like @Jordan said, choosing mysql for your task would be a mistake. You need either some timeseries-specific database, or some nosql db

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't a good fit for this site. You are asking us for opinions on a very broad question lacking detail. You're also asking for references, which is again off-topic. Please read "[ask]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393. I'd recommend further research as logging to databases is a topic you'll find covered.

Comment: @Jordan. If I have 100 sensors with 10 second values it would be over 800 000 writes per hour. And I am planning on being able to log alot more than just 100 sensors.
I have understood now that I should look into other databases than MySQL. Thanks for the feedback.
The use cases are not fully specified yet. The main problem now is just to store that data. We would also want to do analysis on just one series but also correlate different and maybe do PCA analysis on some.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to store timeseries, i would suggest you to take a look on [InfluxDB](https://influxdb.com/).

There are libraries for ruby, which you can use:

https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-ruby

https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-rails

Comment: Coolt. Thanks for the tip. I'll look into it